# Replace char or number with spaces given start position and length

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a specific string I would be given start position and length.

for eg input string `"abcdefgh"` . `start position : 3` and `length :2`. I want to replace characters with space

so the output string should  `" ab   efgh"` .
how can i do that in python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: strings are immutable and iterable - you need to slice it and put the amount of spaces in it

Comment: why should the output string start with a space? why are there 3 spaces inside but only 2 characters removed?

Comment: strings are immutable meaning if you slice and append some characters you are actually creating a new string object. Also, your expected output is a little confusing. Edit your post with your attempt as well to show what you have tried and not worked for you

Answer (score 0):

If you start with

```
a="abcdefgh"
start=3
length=2
```

Then you can slice your string by using indexes and add your chosen number of spaces in the middle this way:

```
b=a[:start-1] + " "*length + a[start-1+length:]
print(b)
```

This outputs:

```
ab  efgh
```

[This answer on slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) mentioned by Patrick above gives a pretty good overview.

Comment: thats different from the (probably ill specified) result in the OP.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I tried to capture the intent of OP and show an actual example for him to move forward with.